# $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+}$ $(\sin x)^{\ln x}$

Tags: calculus

My question is, what is $\lim_{x  \rightarrow 0^+}(\sin x)^{\ln x}$?

This limit is equal to

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} e^{\ln(\sin x)\ln x} = e^{\lim_{x\to0^+} \ln(\sin x)\ln x}$$

But what is right hand side limit of $\ln(\sin x)\ln x$  when x goes to $0$

any suggestion? I cannot apply L'Hospital.

Comment: It should be "If this limit exists, it is equal to", not "This limit is equal to"

Comment: HINT:  $\sin x=x+O(x^3)$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Outline:**

First, when $x\to 0^+$, we have $\sin x > 0$ for $x$ sufficiently small and the quantity is well-defined. Now (the following will rely on Taylor approximations):
$$
\sin x = x + o(x^2)
$$
so
$$
\ln \sin x = \ln( x + o(x^2))  = \ln x + \ln (1+o(x)) = \ln x + o(x)
$$
and 
$$
e^{\ln( \sin x) \cdot \ln x} = e^{(\ln x)^2 + o(x\ln x)}= e^{(\ln x)^2 + o(1)}
$$
as $x\ln x \xrightarrow[x\to 0]{} 0$. To conclude, observing that $(\ln x)^2 \xrightarrow[x\to 0]{} \infty$ will give you the answer by continuity of $\exp$.

Comment: Well done! ... +1

Answer (score 6):

Using a well-known inequality, for $0 < x < 1$ we have

$$1-x < -\ln x < \frac{1- x}{x}. $$

Hence, for $0 < x < 1$

$$\ln x \ln \sin x= (-\ln x )(-\ln \sin x)> -\ln x (1-\sin x)>  - \ln x (1 - \sin 1)\to \infty$$

Comment: The upper bound is just concavity. How does the lower bound work?

Comment: @Ian Those well-known bounds for the logarithm can be obtained in a variety of ways.  One of those is to use the integral definition as $$\log x=\int_1^x \frac{1}{u}\,du$$from which it is clear that $$\frac{x-1}{x}\le \log x \le x-1$$

Comment: @Dr. MV: Thats the argument - thanks.  I just had the inequality reversed for $\ln x < 0$. Corrected.

Comment: @RRL  Well done.  ... +1